# from pyqt4 designer gui how to get radio button value using python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have created gui using pyqt4 designer and covert to this ui to .py but I am unable to access radio button value and also wanna check which radio button is checked using python.
i tried following **code :**

```
a= radiobutton.get()
```

I can not get the value.
 
Please help me

Comment: So, are you getting an error message? Or what?

Comment: Please add more code of your .py file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct method is isChecked:

```
a = radiobutton.isChecked()
```

Comment: how to get value of checked radio button

Comment: `isChecked()` returns a boolean, which is the value. True for checked, False for unchecked.

Comment: how to get the value of dateedit and timeedit controll

Comment: Try the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtcore.html), or just google it.